# Does dd have a problem with sockets?

Tags: dd

I have a script whose stdin is an established TCP socket. A remote sender sends 14000 bytes, and I have in the script

```
dd bs=140000 >/tmp/foo
```

Yet dd only copies 6000 bytes, and if the recv sends something else afterwards such as a short string, dd will copy it to the same file (so dd remains open) but the 14000-6000 bytes are lost.

Comment: Try `bs=1`. Or drop the `dd` part completely, and just redirect the `stdin` to `> /tmp/foo`. Unless the purpose of `dd` is something you didn't mention in your queston, in that case, please edit your question.

Comment: Ah yes I'm stupid I forgot about cat...But nevertheless foo is still only 6000 bytes so I guess the problem is elsewhere. The sender is a Python script and I have used sendall but still no success.

Comment: you can try iflag=fullblock and also try with different stdbuf setting. also check your script that no other program is consuming input. otherwise not sure how to answer since I can't reproduce the issue. do you have a standalone snippet / test case? you could also strace -ff the whole thing, it's a lot of output to go through but when weird things happen, it can sometimes help

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `dd`. It's doing what it's designed to do, but that doesn't match what you want. You could use `iflag=fullblock` to require full blocks on input but it's much easier to use `cat`

```
cat >/tmp/foo
```